# Fix timer starting on page load

Tags: javascript, forms, timer, pageload

A simple Javascript timer that runs for 30 seconds and displays a message once it reaches 0. I cant figure out how to get it to start when a button is pressed instead of on pageload. Any help is appreciated :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sec = 30;   // set the seconds
var min = 00;   // set the minutes

function countDown() {
  sec--;
  if (sec == -01) {
    sec = 59;
    min = min - 1;
  } else {
   min = min;
  }
if (sec<=9) { sec = "0" + sec; }
  time = (min<=9 ? "0" + min : min) + " min and " + sec + " sec ";
if (document.getElementById) { theTime.innerHTML = time; }
  SD=window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
if (min == '00' && sec == '00') { sec = "00"; window.clearTimeout(SD); alert("Too slow."); }
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  countDown();
});
</script>
```

Comment: The main problem is here that you should *analyze the problem and then design a solution*. Don't start coding right away, you end up with code as shown above. Please review your code and remove all the redundant parts. You are making things far too difficult for yourself here. There are tons of tutorials about countdown timers and many not as complex as yours. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add event listener to the button in the load function and then call countDown

```
 addLoadEvent(function() {
   var el = document.getElementById("startButton");   
     el.addEventListener("click", countDown, false); 
});
```

Here the full example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VTS5D/)

Comment: Thanks SirLisko, this helped alot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick='countDown();'>Click Me</button>
```

And just don't call addLoadEvent() at all.

Comment: Upon clicking start, the time displays in my span for about 0.2 seconds then disappears....

    <table>
    <tr><td>
    Time Left = <span id="theTime" class="timeClass"/>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <center>
    <form>
    <input value="Start" type="submit" Name="Start" onClick='countDown();'/>
    </form>
    </center>

Comment: Did you remove the call to addLoadEvent()? The timer code you have has a global timer -- it will only count down once, and will count faster the more you call it.

Comment: Nowhere in the code you've provided do you ever set a value for `theTime` which presumably is an element. Why would you check if document.getElementById exists on every run of your function? That's completely pointless.

Comment: Yeah, I only left the countDown() code. Clicking the button more than once shows the countdown time again, but it resets.. then disappears again...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [full sample](http://jsfiddle.net/xBjRS/1/) with start/stop and remaining time display.

```
var gTimer = null

function endOfTimer() {
    console.log("here");
    window.alert('Too slow');
}

function start() {
    gTimer = window.setTimeout('endOfTimer', 1 * 1000);
}
```